# How to grep at least one character and double slash

Tags: grep

I have a `.gnmap` file which contains rows like the following:

`Host: x.x.x.x () Ports: PORT/open/tcp//PROTOCOL//SERVICE/`

I'd like to grep for `"/open/tcp//at_least_one_character//at_least_one_character/"`

I tried to use `grep "/open/tcp//[a-zA-Z]//[a-zA-Z]//"`, but it does not return anything.

How can I correct the `grep` above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regexp matches only one character after the //
To match at least one character use `+`. It tells grep to mach one or more occurrence of the previous character or character class.

```
 grep -E "/open/tcp//[a-zA-Z]+//[a-zA-Z]+/"
```

`-E` indicates grep to use extended regular expression. You can have a similar behaviour without the -E option, but you need to backslash the `+` to give it a special meaning.

```
 grep  "/open/tcp//[a-zA-Z]\+//[a-zA-Z]\+/"
```